# Openshift Online Rquests with Small Memory Limits Fail

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

With a `memory limit` of 1Gb, requests smaller than 100Mb fail, so we need to know how big our request can be with a limit of 1Gb.

The picture below shows the posted dto object.

[image]

when sends request, it gets failed and cannot complete the request because cannot map posted data to the input dto of endpoint, if we increase the limit to 2Gb, it succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenShift Online:

> For OpenShift Online Pro, the maximum pod memory is 3Gi. The minimum pod or container memory that you can specify is 100Mi.

> For OpenShift Online Starter, the maximum pod memory is 1Gi. The minimum pod or container memory that you can specify is 200Mi.

Take a look at this documentation: [https://docs.openshift.com/online/pro/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#:~:text=For%20OpenShift%20Online%20Starter%2C%20the,you%20can%20specify%20is%20200Mi.&text=The%20name%20of%20the%20limit%20range%20object](https://docs.openshift.com/online/pro/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#:%7E:text=For%20OpenShift%20Online%20Starter%2C%20the,you%20can%20specify%20is%20200Mi.&text=The%20name%20of%20the%20limit%20range%20object).